# Index was outside the bounds of the array in c# : IndexOutOfRange

Tags: c#

Index was outside the bounds of the array in c# : IndexOutOfRange

Comment: How do you know that `filesIndex` was not outside the bounds of the array?  There's nothing in your code that would ensure that structurally.  Add a check before you use the variable and see if it fires.

Comment: @HereticMonkey No.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 Yes it triggers the fire then we see the issue as mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you initialize your array `fileData = new string[2]` with a size of 2. For the 3rd file that matches your condition, fileIndex will be 2 and thus outside the array's bounds.

As you don't know how may files will match on beforehand, use a `List<string>` instead.

Comment: but the issue is in this line  int filesIndex = 0; within the IF loop when i replace 0 with filesIndex that is causing the error. Can you share me the block with the code updated?

Comment: No, the exception occurs at `fileData[filesIndex]`. Make fileData a `List<string>` instead, and `.Add()` to it.

Comment: You mean `var fileData = new List<string();` [...] `fileData.Add(filesIndex.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0'))`?

Comment: Thank you buddy. I appreciate you're inputs.